# how to handle try catch in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, try-catch

I searched my level best to handle @try @catch in iphone application. But, i can not find the exact solution/sample for using @try and @catch statements from google. Can you please help me to implement @try and @catch in my code? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@try {
    crashy code
} @catch (NSException *e) {
    no crash for me
} @finally {
    happens whether the code was successful or not
}
```